# How to add a fallback to a certain language in custom function in React if user has a non-supported language in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, translation

I am trying to add a fallback language functionality to our web app. At the moment if user has a different language than what is supported set as their browser language, the application crashes. I am trying to make it so that if user has a non-supported language at his browser, the application would change the language to English.

I tried using libraries like i18next when creating the translation options in the first place but I didn't get it to work with our app, so after getting some external help this is how we handled our translations:

```
  const currentUser = useSelector(Select.User.current);
  const language = _language || currentUser.language;
  const translations = {
    en,
    de,
    fr,
  };
  const supportedLanguages = Object.keys(translations);
  return [translations[language], supportedLanguages];
}
```

And here is the state controller

```
  const noLanguageSet = !currentUser.language;

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser.current) return;
    if (noLanguageSet) {
      // Select browser language as default
      const browserLang =
        window.navigator.language.split('-')[0] ||
        window.navigator.userLanguage.split('-')[0] ||
        'en';
      actions.editUser({ ...currentUser.ref, language: browserLang });
    }
  }, [currentUser.current]);

  return null;
```

However, I'm quite lost now on how to write the aforementioned fallback functionality in case that user has a browser language that is not supported by our app. All the help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know list of supported languages, you can just specify some default language and use it if user language is not supported.

```js
supportedLanguages.includes(browserLanguage) ? browserLanguage : defaultLanguage;
```